# How img can be centered?

Tags: html, css

I have a img which I need for centering, I try margin: 0 auto; but still can't center the img. How can I?

Thank you

```
<div>
    <img src="../p66.jpg" />
</div>

div{margin:0 auto;width:100%;}
img {margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div{margin:0 auto;width:100%;text-align:center;}
```

You can use text-align: center in container, if you don't have img width. Otherwise, if you set image width, and display: block, margin:0 auto on image will work...

E.g. `img {margin:0 auto;display:block;width:100px}`

Answer (score 1):

So you can do something like this...

**CCS**

```
img.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="blwebcam-sample.jpg" alt="Suni" class="center" />
```

I found this searching Google.

**Source**:  http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/a/aa012207.htm